# How to reiterate function on each row using sapply in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, sapply

I have a data frame with 4 rows. I have to sum current row value and previous row value of the same column, but should iterate till the top the column

```
aa<-data.frame(groupid=c(0:3),var=rep(10,4))
>aa
groupid var
0   10
1   10
2   10
3   10
#if iterating over only 4th row
>i=4

#What I want to achieve->
>for(x in 1:aa$groupid[i]) {
  aa$var[i]<-aa$var[i]+aa$var[i-x]
}
>aa$var[i]
40 #aa$var[4]+aa$var[3]+aa$var[2]+aa$var[1]

#How I want to achieve--> using sapply() as my real data frame is huge and 
#for loop is taking a lot of time

#What I have achieved till now-->
>bb<-sapply(aa$groupid[i], function(x){
  sum(aa$var[i],aa$var[i-x]) 
})
>bb
20 #aa$var[4]+aa$var[3]
```

How do I loop over each row from bottom to top in sapply() for it to resave the value  in the same variable?

Answer (score 1):

Your loop calculates the accumulated sum of all previous rows (including the row that it's being evaluated).

In that case the solution is simple:

```
aa$var2 = cumsum(aa$var)
```

Result:

```
> aa
  groupid var var2
1       0  10   10
2       1  10   20
3       2  10   30
4       3  10   40
```

Comment: I got the answer! Thanks!